# Matlab: brushing out bad data then reconnecting fragments

Tags: matlab, statistics, curve-fitting

I have the below plot that caontained bad data that I brushed out:

[image: plot]

In the middle for example, what is the best way to reconnect the adjacent fragments while completely removing the empty space?

Comment: How did you remove those parts? Did you replace them with `NaN`? And how do you want to reconnect everything? Do you want to push everything left?

Comment: @erfan i just brushed them on the plot and pressed delete and they were replaced by NANs. I simply need to drag the right fragment and connect it to the left one. But I'm not sure which interpolation method i should use in this case.

Comment: assuming your variable is `x` you can just do  `x(a:b) = []` where a and b are the limits you want to cut it by. Or if they are already NaNs then `x(isnan(x))=[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have modified a plot graphically, this is how you access the modified data:

```
Line = get(gca, 'Children');
x_data = Line.XData;
y_data = Line.YData;
```

Then, if you want to keep the fragments where they are and simply connect them, you can ignore the `NaN` data points and plot the rest:

```
id = ~(isnan(x_data(:)) | isnan(y_data(:)));
figure; plot(x_data(id), y_data(id))
```

If you prefer to push all the fragments to the left and connect them, after defining `id` as above, you can do it in this way:

```
firstid = find(id, 1);
figure; plot(x_data(firstid:(firstid + sum(id) - 1)), y_data(id))
```

Comment: I would rather: `ix = ~(isnan(x_data(:)) | isnan(y_data(:))); plot(x_data(ix), y_data(ix));`